# I've been trying to refresh data in PowerBI which is connected to Teradata and I encounter the following error:

Tags: powerbi, teradata

An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'The type initializer for 'Teradata.Client.Provider.WpSession' threw an exception.'

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: First things first - do you have the [.NET Data Provider for Teradata](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/net-data-provider-for-teradata) installed? It doesn't come with PowerBI "out of the box".

Comment: @Fred Thanks a lot. I went ahead and installed the file. 
Now, I face a different error while refreshing the data:
An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'A system call has failed'
Now do I navigate this?

Comment: Hard to say without more detail. Maybe try running PowerBI as administrator and see if you get more info.